# How to call a HttpHandler in MVC Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

We are porting our old Webapp from WebForms to MVC Asp.net , I have creatain HttpHandlers on the old app used for basic reporting.

We were calling them directly i.e www.something.com/handler.ashx?ID=1 on button clicks.

Now I need to port the same functionality in MVC Asp.Net , coding the handler was the easy task but How do I cater the query string and route my request to the Handler ?

Comment: check http://forums.asp.net/t/1320309.aspx/1?How+to+use+a+custom+HttpHandler+in+MVC+ it may contain the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use the handler normal like other applications, no need to routes for using it.
2. If you run your application in IIS7 Integrated mode, the http handler must be defined in handlers element of system.webServer section (httpHandlers section works for IIS6 and IIS7 Classic mode).
3. Also check http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC-custom-ActionResult.aspx, it features an image action result which just uses the standerd ASP.NET MVC lifecycle.

copied from http://forums.asp.net/t/1320309.aspx/1?How+to+use+a+custom+HttpHandler+in+MVC+

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following line to my RouteConfig class in to avoid getting a 404 error when accessing a .ashx handler. The handler was registred in Web.config, and thus not using a ashx file, so another solution woule have been to use the .axd extension instead.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        // MVC routing is ignoring .axd paths by default.
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // This line added to also ignore .ashx files.
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");

        // ...
    }
}
```